# How to Identify Astragalus Species

Tags: species-identification, botany, methods

I have several photos of a plant I believe to be in the genus Astragalus. I would like to determine the particular species in my area, the foot hills of San Diego County. Do I need a microscope to determine species, or can it be determined from the naked eye? How exactly should I proceed?

[image: Pods]
[image: Leaf]
[image: Flowers]